# Instanciar un objeto

Tags: php, php7

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\xxxxxxx;

    use App\XXXX;
    use Monolog\Logger;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;



    class XXXXController extends Controller
    {
        protected $client;
        protected $lmsHeaders;

        function __construct()
        {

            $this->lmsHeaders = [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.env('LMS_TOKEN', false)
            ];

             $this->client = new Client([
                 'headers' => $this->lmsHeaders
            ]);

            parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function searchUser(int $studentId)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $userResponse = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . env('MY_TEST_TOKEN', false)
            ],
            'form_params' => $userData->toArray()
        ]);
    }
```

Actualmente , lo que hago es en el método **searchUser** crear un objeto **client** cada vez , pero teniéndolo en el constructor entiendo que tendría
que poder hacer algo como esto:

`self::client->request(...) o $this->client` pero en ambos casos me da error , cual seria la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que da? ¿La clase tiene una propiedad llamada `client`? Deberías mostrar cómo empieza la clase (código antes del constructor).

Comment: He editado el primer post con la información que me pides. Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: en principio deberia funcionarte `$this->client->request...`. que error te da?

Comment: $test = $this->client->request(); ==> me dice este error : Using $this when not in object context

Comment: en que linea te esta dando error? en el constructor o en searchUser?

Comment: vale. La cosa parece ser que estas llamando desde un static a elementos que son de objeto, cosa que no es correcta. Puedes probar a cambiar la funcion `searchUser` sin el static?

Comment: El error me lo da en searchUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando llamar a las propiedades del objeto `XXXXController` desde un método de clase (estático). Esto no es posible, porque, aunque el método `static` sea accesible, las propiedades del objeto no están definidas hasta la reserva de memoria del objeto `XXXXController`.

Lo contrario (acceder a métodos estáticos desde algún método de objeto) si es posible, porque ya esta definido dicho método.

En tu caso, para solucionar esto, puedes quitar el `static` del método static que has definido.Entonces el método `SearchUser` pasara a ser de objeto. Cuando definas un objeto de la clase `XXXXController`,

```
$objeto = new XXXXController();
```

Entonces podrás hacer la llamada de `$objeto->searchUser()` y este método podrá llamar a las propiedades del objeto `$objeto`.

Comment: Muchas gracias...ahora he visto el problema. Gracias